# how can i list the updates using wordpress xml rpc methods

Tags: ios, wordpress, xml-rpc, updates

in my iphone app i am trying to list all the updates from the users but i didnt get any `XML-RPC methods` to do so 
can any one tell me , how can i list the updates using **wordpress xml rpc methods** , like how we list **posts** and **comments** using `wp.getPosts and wp.GetComments`, i have searched for the method but i didnt get any.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.leoganda.net/xml-rpc-on-iphone/) to get data from your wordpress site

you add the library to your project and add code to your project send xml request to your site and get data unser xml format and parse it.

Comment: tanx for ur reply,,,That i know,,and also i am getting responses for wp.getPosts and wp.GetComments and other methods,,,but i couldn't find a method to list user updates